# OCI runtime exec failed

Tags: docker, docker-compose

since today i have got an error message with various docker commands. Unfortunately I don't really know what to do with it. Does anyone have any idea what the problem could be and how I fix it?

Error:

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:95: starting setns process caused: fork/exec /proc/self/exe: resource temporarily unavailable: unknown
```

Another Error:

```
ERROR: for hosting_mail_1  Cannot start service mail: OCI runtime create failed: unable to retrieve OCI runtime error (open /run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/moby/5fabf9edf67fbd6455bdc955c56c063683aa78e8e31514660661799aaa867391/log.json: no such file or directory): runc did not terminate successfully: unknown

ERROR: for mail  Cannot start service mail: OCI runtime create failed: unable to retrieve OCI runtime error (open /run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/moby/5fabf9edf67fbd6455bdc955c56c063683aa78e8e31514660661799aaa867391/log.json: no such file or directory): runc did not terminate successfully: unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Comment: what is your env, OS, docker version, what did you do before this error occurred?

Comment: ubuntu, docker 20.10.3, and I have done nothing than start other docker-composes before. But today the error suddenly disappeared without changing anything. But if you have an idea what it could have been, I would be very happy if you share your ideas

Comment: how many containers do you running? feels like reached some kind of limits

Comment: there were 4 containers running and I tried to start 3 other

Comment: is there any other error msg by running `journalctl -u docker`

Comment: can't execute commands anymore. docker broke my server... I had to rollback it

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you solved your problem finally, but this really looks like bad file system authorization that may have been corrupted from an update on the file systems.

Regarding the error : `container_linux.go:370:`,/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/moby/5fabf9edf67fbd6455bdc955c56c063683aa78e8e31514660661799aaa867391/log.json

I can see that :

- docker manage to initiate a volume ID
- did not manage to mount that volume on the disk

0/ Check docker basic command

```
docker ps 
docker images
docker pull ubuntu:latest
```

If one of these commands is failing, you are up to review docker installation, seems that maybe docker is not installed properly.

1/
To check if you need to completely re-install docker, you may try the following basic command

```
docker run --name checkDocker  -it ubuntu:latest bash
```

If this is not displaying any docker shell, then you have a problem on running a container, not necessarly docker installation.

2/
Check your docker volumes and rights, I don't have your installation setup, but It seems you are using docker-compose and maybe there is some conflicts when mounting the volume of your containers with specific rights and the host's rights and user id

3/
If you are ending up here you should follow that work around of re-installation, which would be the fatest solution to restore your application if you have backup (hope you have )